# Rails conditional required for input tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm working on building a form in which one of the question types is a yes/no question. If a user selects "no", they will be required to fill out a text box explaining why they chose no. I would like to make the text box required if the user selects no, but not required if the user selects yes. This is what my code looks like

```
<% @questions.each_with_index do |question, index| %>
  ...

  <div class="radio-button">
    <%= radio_button_tag("questions[#{question.id}][answer][name]", "yes", false, required: true) %>
    <%= label_tag("questions[#{question.id}][answer][name]_yes", "Yes") %>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button">
    <%= radio_button_tag("questions[#{question.id}][answer][name]", "no", false, required: true) %>
    <%= label_tag("questions[#{question.id}][answer][name]_no", "No") %>
  </div>
  <div class="explanation">
    <%= label_tag("questions[#{question.id}][answer][explanation]", "If no, please explain why.") %>
    <div>
      <%= text_area_tag("questions[#{question.id}][answer][explanation]", nil, size: "50x8", title: "question-#{index + 1}-text") %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How can I make that last text_area_tag required if the user selected the no radio button, but not required if the user selected yes? I imagine I will have to add something along the lines of

```
<%= text_area_tag(..., required: ([condition] ? true : false) %>
```

But I'm not sure how to write the condition. Is it possible to target a radio button and see if it is checked? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do that on the client you have to use javascript.

Comment: Thanks I was wondering if there was some built in rails trick to do so without js

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, you want the required status of the textarea to change based on the user interacting with the radio buttons, before the form (I assume there is a form encapsulating all this?) is submitted back to the server?

Comment: This is done on client side with javascript or jquery. It is impossible to predict what will user select before he does it.

Answer (score 0):

its all really depends on what the condition is

I am thinking that the conditions are parts of the params

```
<% if params['something'] == 'true' %>

  <%= text_area_tag(...) %>

<% else %>

  <%= text_area_tag(..., required: params['something']) %>

<% else %>
```

I hope that this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= text_area_tag(..., ([condition] ? {required: true} : {})) %>
```